# TreeMap putting BigDecimal key with trailing zero after decimal has no effect

Tags: java, hashmap, bigdecimal, treemap

Putting value in key in Map not adding value in key

```
public static void putKey() {
    TreeMap<BigDecimal,String> trmap = new TreeMap<BigDecimal,String>();
    MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(3.1,mc);
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(3.10,mc);
    BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal(3.2,mc);
    BigDecimal b4 = new BigDecimal(3.3,mc);
    BigDecimal b5 = new BigDecimal(3.4,mc);
    
    trmap.put(b1, "3.1");
    trmap.put(b2, "3.10");
    trmap.put(b3, "3.2");
    trmap.put(b4, "3.3");
    trmap.put(b5, "3.4");
    
    System.out.println(trmap);
}
```

in the above map 3.10 is not added in the key.

so I have tried to compute the hash code for both values

```
public static void putKey() {
    TreeMap<BigDecimal, String> trmap = new TreeMap<BigDecimal, String>();
    MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(3.1, mc);
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(3.10, mc);
    BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal(3.2, mc);
    BigDecimal b4 = new BigDecimal(3.3, mc);
    BigDecimal b5 = new BigDecimal(3.4, mc);

    trmap.put(b1, "3.1");
    trmap.put(b2, "3.10");
    trmap.put(b3, "3.2");
    trmap.put(b4, "3.3");
    trmap.put(b5, "3.4");

    System.out.println(trmap);
    int hashcodeb1 = b1.hashCode();
    int hashcodeb2 = b2.hashCode();

    System.out.println("3.1-->" + hashcodeb1);
    System.out.println("3.10-->" + hashcodeb2);
}
```

both hash code are computing the same value my requirement is that I want to put both both values in my map, So with some help of other forum post it looks like I have to override `hashCode()` method but it returns int as value and I am not sure it will help in my case.

I have written `hashCode()` in my class

```
public class BigDecimalMap {
    public BigDecimalMap() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimalMap bigDecimalMap = new BigDecimalMap();
        putKey();
        }
    
        public static void putKey() {
            TreeMap<BigDecimal, String> trmap = new TreeMap<BigDecimal, String>();
            MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
            BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(3.1, mc);
            BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(3.10, mc);
            BigDecimal b3 = new BigDecimal(3.2, mc);
            BigDecimal b4 = new BigDecimal(3.3, mc);
            BigDecimal b5 = new BigDecimal(3.4, mc);
    
            trmap.put(b1, "3.1");
            trmap.put(b2, "3.10");
            trmap.put(b3, "3.2");
            trmap.put(b4, "3.3");
            trmap.put(b5, "3.4");
    
            System.out.println(trmap);
            int hashcodeb1 = b1.hashCode();
            int hashcodeb2 = b2.hashCode();
    
            System.out.println("3.1-->" + hashcodeb1);
            System.out.println("3.10-->" + hashcodeb2);
        }
        
        public int hashCode() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Please help in identifying how to add both values.

Comment: what do you think is the difference between `3.1` and `3.10`?

Comment: how about changing the hashcode so that it is computed from the length of the string + BigDecimal.hashCode?

Comment: retrieving some value from some location that might not be big decimal may be String and i Have to take decision based on both values , Earlier i have tried float and double but they do not work . So i have read in post to use BigDecimal for  calculation

Comment: that's i want to do to override it but how ? @http://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat

Comment: Why do you think you need to associate `BigDecimal`s with string representations of those decimals?

Comment: who it should be wriiten for my class @Scary Wombat Help needed

Comment: for sorting puporse @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: A TreeMap doesn't care about the hashCode. It compares its keys using their natural ordering (i.e. compareTo), and 3.1 and 3.10 are considered equal by this natural ordering. Even if you were using a HashMap (which uses hashCode), you would need to override hashCode in the key class (i.e. in BigDecimal), and not in the class that uses the map. You should explain what you're trying to achieve, because the way you're doing it won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to Javadoc of [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface.

Since `compareTo` of `BigDecimal` is not consistent to `equals`(compareTo may return 0 but equals return false).
Use `HashMap` instead which consider `hashCode` and `equals` for the key.

Refer to Javadoc of [BigDecimal#equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method

> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality. Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

As we execute the following code

```java
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2);
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal(3.1, mc);
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal(3.10, mc);
System.out.println(b1.doubleValue());
System.out.println(b2.doubleValue());
System.out.println(b1.scale());
System.out.println(b2.scale());
System.out.println(b1.compareTo(b2));
System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
System.out.println(b1.hashCode());
System.out.println(b2.hashCode());
```

Since b1 and b2 has same value and scale, they are considered to be same Object.

Then we compare b1 and b2 with different scale with below code.
Inorder to create BigDeciaml with different scale, use the constructor with String instead of double(refer to the note https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(double)).

```java
BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("3.1");
BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("3.10");
System.out.println(b1.doubleValue());
System.out.println(b2.doubleValue());
System.out.println(b1.scale());
System.out.println(b2.scale());
System.out.println(b1.compareTo(b2));
System.out.println(b1.equals(b2));
System.out.println(b1.hashCode());
System.out.println(b2.hashCode());
```

Comment: This is all true, but it's irrelevant, since a TreeMap doesn't use hashCode and equals.

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet so i cannot implement a over ride of hashCode() in my class

Comment: If you try the second piece of code, you will find there is no need to override hash code. Usually overriding hash code method is only needed for custom created class. In addition, the overriding should be done on the class you are using for the key(BigDecimal).Overriding hashCode of BigDecimalMap.will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

A `Treemap` is implemented as a Red-Black-Tree; one which cares about how `compareTo` is implemented, since it has to move your entry either to the `left` or `right`.

So a `TreeMap` only cares about how your keys implement `compareTo` method. Now if you look at this code:

```
    BigDecimal b1 = new BigDecimal("3.1");
    BigDecimal b2 = new BigDecimal("3.10");

    System.out.println(b1.compareTo(b2)); // this prints zero since
                        // they are the same according to compareTo

    TreeMap<BigDecimal, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
    map.put(b1, "aaa");
    map.put(b2, "bbb");

    System.out.println(map); // {3.1=bbb}
```

Notice that at the end, after two inserts there is only a single Entry in the TreeMap. That happens because `b1` and `b2` are the same(according to `compareTo`), so the value is replaced in the map after the second insert.